# Codeigniter Facebook app POST method AND query_string

Tags: facebook, codeigniter

I have a toy facebook app I'm playing with so I can understand how it all works. It's fine if you go the the app like this: http://apps.facebook.com/pushup-challenge/ (and connect it). But if you then go to it from your facebook page, FB uses the URL http://apps.facebook.com/pushup-challenge/?ref=bookmarks.

In my log file, I see that FB is POSTing the data and including the /?ref=bookmarks to it's call to my codeigniter system. This is causing it to either say "invalid URI parameters" or give me a 404, depending on if I've edited the system/core/URI.php file to add rawurlencode() to a particular call.

I've tried using mod_rewrite to get rid of the query_string, too, but since it's POSTing, it doesn't appear to be working (though I'm not exactly sure why).

Has anyone else run into this? How did you fix it?

Thanks in advance,
Hans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `$config['uri_protocol'] = “PATH_INFO”;` and set `enable_query_strings = TRUE` 
or
set

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-?=';
```

in config.php

Answer (score 0):

Because it isn't calling your file by name (just ?ref=bookmarks) the server runs thru the standard default files: index.htm, index.html, index.asp. Because you need to accept a POST, you need a server that allows POSTs to htm & html if you choose to use those. Index.asp will accept POSTs on most servers, and that works for me.
SOLUTION: Add a file (index.asp), that calls the real app that you named in the App settings.